# How to use date filter in FrontApp API call to get data for certain period of time

Tags: rest, postman, alteryx, workfront-api

I'm using this API call to fetch the data from FrontApp but this API is not getting me data for that date range.
I have used this API call in Postman - there I'm not getting any error but unable to get the data for a specific date range. Here is the Rest API which I'm using to get the data:

[https://api2.frontapp.com/events?after="2018-06-18T16:00:00.000Z"&before="2019-06-18T16:00:00.000Z"](https://api2.frontapp.com/events?after=%222018-06-18T16:00:00.000Z%22&before=%222019-06-18T16:00:00.000Z%22)

Here is API documentation of FrontApp.
https://dev.frontapp.com/reference/events-1

Can someone help me on this I'm very new to this regarding using Postman and API calls.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution for this query:

[https://api2.frontapp.com/events?q[before]=1612883716&q[after]=1612192516](https://api2.frontapp.com/events?q%5Bbefore%5D=1612883716&q%5Bafter%5D=1612192516)

Comment: How about searching contacts with contact number? Do they have any specific documentation on "q" query structure?